# Can't set headers after they are sent with chat irc bot in express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, http

I'm building a chat bot that will moderate chat and respond to commands sent by a user in chat.

I'm also trying to set this up in an express server so I can start and stop the bot as well as manage commands and the like in a web app so I don't have to run the bot from my terminal all the time.

I have my files set up similar to the `express-generator` like this

```
node_modules
routes
  - api
    - bot.js
  api.js
server.js
```

In server.js

```
...
var api = require('./routes/api');

app.use('/api/v'+apiVersion, api);
...
```

In `routes/api.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// API's
var bot = require('./api/bot');

// Endpoints
router.route('/bot')
    .post(function(req,res) { bot.startBot(req,res) })
    .delete(function(req,res) { bot.stopBot(req,res) });

module.exports = router;
```

In `routes/api/bot.js`

```
var config = require('../../config');

var irc = require('tmi.js');

var chatBotOptions = {
  options: {
    debug: true,
  },
  identity: {
    username: config.username,
    password: config.password
  },
  channels: config.channels
};
var chatBot = new irc.client(chatBotOptions);

module.exports.startBot = function(req,res){
  // Connect chatBot
  chatBot.connect();
  chatBot.on('join', function(channel, username){
    chatBot.say(channel, 'Hello there!');
    res.json({action:'joined'});
  });
};
module.exports.stopBot = function(req,res){
  // Disconnect chatBot
  chatBot.say(config.channels[0],"I'm out!");
  chatBot.disconnect();
  res.json({action:'disconnecting'});
};
chatBot.on('chat', function(channel, user, message, self){
  chatBot.say(channel, "Kappa");
});
```

In my front end I make an ajax call to those end points using the proper http verb to start and stop the bot. The problem happens when the `startBot` endpoint is hit, then the `stopBot` and then `startBot` is called again, the bot connects to the irc channel, but I guess when the `res.json` message is sent I get this error. I am reading that is has something to do with callbacks of sorts but I'm just not sure where that would be as `res.json` is only sent in one place and I'm not even sure if that's where the problem is.

Here is the error stack

```
_http_outgoing.js:335
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
          ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/jordanriser/workspace/twitch_bot/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:718:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/jordanriser/workspace/twitch_bot/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:163:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/jordanriser/workspace/twitch_bot/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:249:15)
    at client.<anonymous> (/Users/jordanriser/workspace/twitch_bot/routes/api/bot.js:25:9)
    at client.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at client.handleMessage (/Users/jordanriser/workspace/twitch_bot/node_modules/tmi.js/lib/client.js:362:30)
    at /Users/jordanriser/workspace/twitch_bot/node_modules/tmi.js/lib/client.js:602:18
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at client._onMessage (/Users/jordanriser/workspace/twitch_bot/node_modules/tmi.js/lib/client.js:600:11)
17 Aug 13:39:05 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has to do with the fact that you're adding an event handler that gets executed more than once on the same EventEmitter instance.

So this:

```
chatBot.on('join', function(channel, username){
  chatBot.say(channel, 'Hello there!');
  res.json({action:'joined'});
});
```

should instead be like:

```
// .once() instead of .on()
chatBot.once('join', function(channel, username){
  chatBot.say(channel, 'Hello there!');
  res.json({action:'joined'});
});
```

However this could still cause errors if the client who made the request closes the connection early before the `join` event gets emitted. To combat this, you might check that the request's socket is still writable before calling `res.json()`:

```
chatBot.once('join', function(channel, username){
  chatBot.say(channel, 'Hello there!');
  if (req.socket.writable)
    res.json({action:'joined'});
});
```